# When I write a Macro with C++, it gives error like "the declaration has no storage type"

Tags: visual-c++, c-preprocessor

When I write a Macro which C++, it is processing error with "the declaration has no storage type", and this is my code, what's wrong with it? If I implement with function, it works well. It doubts me.

```
#define FLAG_CLEAR_MUL_BIT(op,beg,end) do{\
long _dwFlag = 0;\
for (int _i = 0; _i < end - beg;++_i)\
{\
    _dwFlag |= (1 << _i);\
}\
_dwFlag = _dwFlag << beg;\
_dwFlag = ~_dwFlag;\    
op = op & _dwFlag;\ // preprocessing wrong:This declaration has no storage type,if impletment with inline function,it works well
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a `while(0)` at the end? You also have whitespace at the end of the line before the error, after the backslash. Remove that.

Comment: The backslash before the comment `// preprocessing wrong...` doesn't escape the newline. Therefore your macro ends before the last `}`. Further you need to end the `do` clause with a `while(false);`.

Comment: yes,i paste code with missing while(0),it's my mistake,thanks for your help

Answer (score -2):

it maybe vs2017 editor bug,i annotate the code and write it again in another place,it compiled!! so magical.

Comment: Don't think so. If you didn't change the code it won't work. The `do` clause is incomplete.